# How to compute the standard error of a simple yes/no survey?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, standard-error

I surveyed 100 voters and found 53% voted for candidate A and 47% voted for candidate B.  I am trying to compute the *t*-statistic from first principles (testing the null hypothesis that the true result is $\theta = 0.42$).

How do I compute the standard error from my sample?

Comment: the *survey* doesn't have a [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error). What statistic from the survey are you trying to compute the standard error of? There's several possibilities.

Comment: @Glen_b I mean what are the chances he's not asking about the mean (or the proportion of successful trials since this is bernoulli)

Comment: @Tilefish could be asking about the standard error of the number voting for A.  Could be asking for the standard error of the difference in votes or the difference in vote proportions. Could be asking about the standard error of the sample standard deviation, counting A votes as 1 and B votes as 0. We should not be guessing. Yes, OP probably means the most obvious thing but asking clear unambiguous questions is important, for several reasons

Comment: @lebel What formulas do you have that relate to this? - presumably you have notes and textbook. What [searches and reasearch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) did you do and what did you find by doing them? See [help/on-topic] relating to homework-style questions and adjust your question appropriately

Comment: To help clarify, I've included my hypothesis-testing motivation.  My textbook (Wooldridge's _Introductory Economics_) says the _t_-statistic can be computed as (0.53 - 0.42) over the standard error, where standard error = standard deviation over square root of _n_ (or 10, in my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm kicking myself now because this is really basic stuff, but I'll leave it up because none of the other websites which helped me look as clean and ad-free as this one.  I'm trying to compute a $t$-statistic

$$t = \sqrt{n}(\bar{y}-\mu_0)/s=(\bar{y}-\mu_0)/se(\bar{y})$$

I couldn't quite put my finger on $se(\bar{y})$, the standard error, except that my *Introductory Econometrics* textbook (by Wooldridge) said $se(\bar{y}) = s / \sqrt{n}$.

The answer to calculating the standard deviation $s$ from the experiment is, of course:

$$s^2 = \frac{p(1-p)}{{n}}$$

In my case, $s = \sqrt{\frac{0.53(1-0.53)}{100}} = 0.0499$.  Hence a $t$-statistic of 2.204.

Comment: t=22 cannot be correct. It's way too large.

Comment: @amoeba Is there something wrong with my calc?  Or logic? Or understanding of basic statistics?

Comment: Well, how did you get 22?

Comment: It looks like a calculation error to me.

Comment: $s^2$ should not have a $\sqrt{}$ in it (I have removed it for you, since you are correct later on when you give a figure for $s$). Your final figure (the t-statistic) is not correct. You made a small calculation error in computing $\frac{0.53-0.42}{0.04991}$.

Comment: \[Additionally many people would use the null value for the proportion in the standard error (i.e. 0.42) and compute a $Z$ rather than a $t$ -- though this is not an error - just a slightly different version of the test ... e.g. see [here](http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/sas/sas6-categoricaldata/SAS6-CategoricalData2.html) or [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/statprogram/node/164) \]

Comment: @Glen_b That's $\frac{0.53 - 0.42}{0.04991}$ times $\sqrt{n}$, no?

Comment: No. You've already done the $\sqrt{n}$ in there.